# warning: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored

Tags: compiler-warnings

REGPARM is defined as:

```
#if __GNUC__ >= 3
#define REGPARM(num)    __attribute__((regparm(num)))
#else
#if defined (_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
#define REGPARM(num)    __fastcall
#else
#define REGPARM(num)
#endif
#endif
```

There is a lot of warnings: 'regparm' attribute directive ignored. How can I (safely) remove them? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get rid of them by [`__APPLE__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651759/any-low-level-macro-is-defined-to-indentify-iphone-os-w-o-include-any-apple-heade)