# Any low-level macro is defined to indentify iPhone OS w/o include any Apple header?

Tags: iphone, macros

When compiling a vanilla iPhone project, any macro is defined to identify the platform is on iPhone OS, even when *no* header file is included?

TARGET_OS_MAC or TARGET_OS_IPHONE-like macros are not defined if no header is included.

So I am looking for macros defined at the similar level of __cplusplus , __GNUC__ , _MSC_VER ... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcc -x objective-c -E -dM /dev/null
```

- `-E`: Run preprocessor only
- `-dM`: Dump `#define`'s.
- `-`: Read from source code stdin
- `-x objective-c`: Treat the source code as ObjC.

Comment: Thanks! \_\_APPLE\_\_ , \_\_OBJC\_\_ and \_\_APPLE\_CC\_\_ are good choices.

Comment: These are incorrect however..  as they also are set for OS X compilations too.